# Windows phone Apps using Express edition with SDK?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am looking  forward to  develop  windows  phone  apps  targeting  windows  phone 7  and  8.

I am using  windows  7  professional..

I am  going  to  install  visual  studio   2013 express   edition for  windows..

with  addition  of  windows  phone  SDK  8 ..

will  windows  7  supports  all  this ??

do  I  need  to  upgrade  to  other  version  of  windows??

if  there  is  a chance  to  use  in  windows  7 .. can you provide  steps  please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

> ### System Requirements
>
> Supported Operating System
>
> Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro

Comment: I have got some modified installer for the Windows Phone 8 SDK that quotes as it will run on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Steps prescribed  by  them  install the SDK, 
1. Download the Windows Phone 8 SDK iso file. You can get it at [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Link...34&clcid=0x409)
2. extract the contents of the ISO to the location of your choosing. 
3. Download the modified "WPexpress_full.exe"[link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2217648&d=1377635703) that is attached to this post and use it to replace the one in the iso. 
4. run setup as normal.